# mysql vars on between date range avoid repeating

Tags: mysql, variables, dry

I'm not sure if its possible or not but can I use set vars to avoid repeating the date range on the following query?  So I would declare TY and LY only once and re-use in the query?

```
// ThisYear -- '2013-02-04 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-10 23:59:59'
// LastYear -- '2012-02-06 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-12 23:59:59'

SELECT 
  count(*) as total_num_bookings,

  SUM(if(book_date BETWEEN '2013-02-04 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-10 23:59:59', 1, 0)) AS num_bookings_ty,
  SUM(if(book_date BETWEEN '2012-02-06 00:00:00' AND '2012-02-12 23:59:59', 1, 0)) AS num_bookings_ly,
  sj.pu_country

FROM 
  pc_tech.sales_journal_default sj

WHERE (book_date BETWEEN '2013-02-04 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-10 23:59:59') OR  (book_date BETWEEN '2012-02-06 00:00:00' AND '2012-02-12 23:59:59' )
group by pu_country
order by total_num_bookings DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
SET @ThisYear1='2013-02-04 00:00:00', @ThisYear2='2013-02-10 23:59:59'
SET @LastYear1='2012-02-06 00:00:00', @LastYear2='2013-02-12 23:59:59'

SELECT 
  count(*) as total_num_bookings,

  SUM(if(book_date BETWEEN @ThisYear1 AND @ThisYear2, 1, 0)) AS num_bookings_ty,
...
```

**Edit**

Or use prepared statements:

```
SET @ThisYear="'2013-02-04 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-10 23:59:59'";
SET @LastYear="'2012-02-06 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-12 23:59:59'";

SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT count(*) as total_num_bookings, SUM(if(book_date BETWEEN ", @ThisYear, ", 1, 0)) AS num_bookings_ty, ...");
PREPARE stmt from @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
...
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: does it need to be 4 variables?  can it be two one for this year and one for last year?

Comment: @Robbo_UK - you could do it using prepared statements, if that fits. See my updated answer.